# What is the difference between <f:viewParam> and <f:param>?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

What is the difference between `<f:viewParam>` and `<f:param>` in JSF 2.1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply put:

`<f:viewParam>` is used inside `<f:metadata>` to attach an `UIViewParameter` as metadata for the current view. For example, if you access the page `myapp/check.jsf?id=3` and your `check.jsf` page has this:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{mrBean.id}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

The value `3` will be set on `mrBean`'s `id` property when the page is loaded.

On the other hand, `<f:param>` sets a parameter in the parent (enclosing) component of this tag, accessible later by obtaining the component's parameters themselves. This is in particular really powerful (yet, disastrous if used wrong) because through `EL` you can achieve some interesting results.

It can be used in different contexts. [This link](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-param-example/) provides an interesting range of applications.